# "Classlike is not defined or imported anywhere." on non-standard annotations (e.g. @prepare, @access)

Tags: php, annotations, atom-editor, phpdoc, serenata

[php-ide-serenata](https://atom.io/packages/php-ide-serenata) 4.5.1 gives me this error:

> Classlike is not defined or imported anywhere.

on this annotation

```php
/**
 * @prepare foo
 */
public function bar()
{
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Serenata only recognizes standard phpDocumentor annotation tags, see https://github.com/Gert-dev/php-ide-serenata/issues/349#issuecomment-340275376

As a workaround, you can add an empty class, just below your regular class, like that:

```php
class prepare {}
```

You only need to do this *once* per namespace.